# What does 'followed by' mean?

Tags: meaning

> If you are using a desktop computer, **simply click A icon followed by
>   the B Icon from your browser.**

Does it mean "On your browser, click A, and then click B" or "On your browser, click A which is located right next to the B icon"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The former. In an instruction, "do X to A, followed by B" will generally mean doing X to A, then doing X to B as well.

Instructions might alternatively take the form "do X to A, followed by doing Y to B".

"Followed by" in contexts other than instructions, such as descriptions, will usually mean that one already follows the other, be it in space, time, sort order, or whatever.